# Java Chat stops working for future clients when X on GUI is pressed

Tags: java, user-interface, server, client, chat

I am having trouble with this where I have server - client connection working and any number of clients can connect to the chat and send messages to each other. But if somebody exits the GUI by clicking the X in upper right corner, everything goes to **** and future clients that join can't do anything.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatC extends JFrame {

//Attributes
private JTextArea msgArea = new JTextArea();
private JTextField input = new JTextField(45);
private JTextArea onlineUsers;
private ArrayList<String> clientNames;
private String clientName = null;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private Socket client;

/**
 * ChatC constructor
 * Creates an interactive GUI for the user
 * Establishes connection with the server
 */
public ChatC() {

    clientName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username:");
    if (clientName == null || clientName.equals("")) clientName = "Guest" + 
    (int) (Math.random() * 200);

    setSize(600, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Welcome to Connect Four chat room,  " + clientName);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JButton sendMsg = new JButton("ENTER");
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(sendMsg);

    msgArea.setEditable(false);

    JPanel south = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(msgArea);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    onlineUsers = new JTextArea();
    onlineUsers.setEditable(false);
    add(onlineUsers, BorderLayout.EAST);
    south.add(input, BorderLayout.WEST);
    south.add(sendMsg, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Logout");
    menu.add(exit);
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(menu);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for playing Connect Four!", "Farewell", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            try{

                out.writeObject("////" + clientName);
                out.flush();

            }
            catch (IOException e1) {}

        }//end of actionPerformed()

    });//end of anonymous ActionListener

    setVisible(true);

    try{

        client = new Socket("localhost", 16789);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(clientName);

        sendMsg.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                if (input.getText() != null && !input.getText().equals("")) {
                    try{

                        out.writeObject(input.getText());
                        out.flush();

                    }//end of try
                    catch (IOException ioe){}

                    input.setText(null);

                }//end of if

            }//end of actionPerformed()

        });//end of anonymous ActionListener

    }//end of try
    catch (UnknownHostException uhe){}
    catch (IOException ioe) {}

    ChatCInner chatInner = new ChatCInner(client);
    chatInner.start();

}//end of ChatC()

/**
 * Main method
 * @param args Project arguments array
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ChatC();
}

/**
 * Method that displays names of users that are currently participating in the chat room
 */
protected void setOnlineUsers(){

    onlineUsers.setText("Users Online: \n");

    for (Object o : clientNames) {

        onlineUsers.append(o + "\n");

    }//end of for each

}//end of setOnlineUsers()

/**
 * Inner class that functions as a thread for each client
 * Handles user's actions on the GUI and communication with the server
 */
private class ChatCInner extends Thread {

    //Attributes
    Object obj;
    ObjectInputStream in;
    Socket clientC;

    /**
     * ChatCInner constructor
     * @param cl Client socket
     */
    public ChatCInner(Socket cl){

        clientC = cl;

    }//end of ChatCInner()

    /**
     * Method that defines what each thread does
     * Handles client interaction(sending messages etc.)
     */
    public void run() {

        try{

            in = new ObjectInputStream(clientC.getInputStream());

            while ( (obj = in.readObject()) != null ) {

                if (obj instanceof String) {

                    msgArea.append((String) obj);
                    msgArea.setCaretPosition(msgArea.getDocument().getLength());

                }//end of if

                if (obj instanceof ArrayList) {

                    clientNames = (ArrayList<String>) obj;

                    if ( (clientNames.indexOf(clientName) == -1) ) {

                        client.close();
                        System.exit(1);

                    }//end of if
                    else setOnlineUsers();

                }//end of if

            }//end of while loop

        }//end of try
        catch (NullPointerException npe) {}
        catch (IOException ioe) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Server was shut down... leaving chat room.", "Server malfunctioning",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE );
            System.exit(1);

        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {}

    }//end of run()

}//end of ChatInner class

}//end of ChatC class
```

This is client

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ChatS extends JFrame {

//Attributes
private ArrayList<String> clientNames = new ArrayList<>();
private Vector<ObjectOutputStream> outList = new Vector<>();
private Socket client = null;

/**
 * ChatS constructor
 * Build simple GUI with a button to terminate server
 * Establishes connection with clients
 */
public ChatS() {

    setTitle("Server Operational");
    setSize(300, 150);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

    JButton stopServer = new JButton("Terminate Server");

    try{

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(16789);

        JLabel localhost = new JLabel(InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString());
        JLabel hostName = new JLabel(InetAddress.getByName("localhost").toString());
        add(localhost);
        add(hostName);

        stopServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.exit(0);

            }//end of actionPerformed()

        });

        add(stopServer);
        setVisible(true);

        while (true) {

            client = server.accept();
            ChatSInner st = new ChatSInner(client);
            st.start();

        }//end of while loop

    }//end of try
    catch(IOException ioe){}

}//end of ChatS()

/**
 * Main method
 * @param args Project arguments array
 */
public static void main(String[] args){ new ChatS(); }

/**
 * Inner class that functions as a thread
 * Handles user interaction on the chat
 */
public class ChatSInner extends Thread {

    //Attributes
    private int index;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private Socket clientInner;

    /**
     * ChatSInner constructor
     * Handles clients as separate threads
     * @param cl Socket of the client
     */
    public ChatSInner(Socket cl){

        try {

            clientInner = cl;
            in = new ObjectInputStream(clientInner.getInputStream());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientInner.getOutputStream());
            outList.add(out);

        }//end of try
        catch(IOException ioe){}

    }//end of ChatSInner()

    /**
     * Method to broadcasts message to all clients connected to chat
     * @param msg Message that a client is sharing with everyone
     */
    protected void sendMsg(String msg){

        try {

            for (ObjectOutputStream out2 : outList){

                out2.writeObject(msg + "\n");
                out2.reset();

            }//end of for each

        }//end of try
        catch(IOException ioe){}

    }//end of sendMsg()

    /**
     * Method that sends ArrayList of online users back to each client
     */
    protected void sendArrayList(){

        try{

            for (ObjectOutputStream out2 : outList) {

                out2.writeObject(clientNames);
                out2.reset();

            }//end of for each

        }//end of try
        catch(IOException ioe){}

    }//end of sendArrayList()

    /**
     * Method that defines what each thread does
     * Handles client interaction in the chat room (sending messages etc.)
     */
    public void run() {

        String clientName;

        try{

            Object obj;
            clientName = (String) in.readObject();
            clientNames.add(clientName);
            index = clientNames.indexOf(clientName);

            sendMsg(clientName + " has entered the chat room.\n");
            sendArrayList();

            while ((obj = in.readObject()) != null){

                if (obj instanceof String) {

                    if ( (((String) obj).length() > 4 ) && ( (String) obj).substring(0, 4).equals("////") ){

                        sendMsg(clientNames.get(index) + " has logged out of the chat room.\n");
                        clientNames.remove(clientName);
                        sendArrayList();

                    } //end of if
                    else sendMsg(clientName + ": " + obj);

                }//end of if

            }//end of while loop

        } //end of try
        catch(IOException ioe){}
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {}

    }//end of run()

}//end of ChatSInner class

}//end of ChatS class
```

THis is server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First lets prevent your server from crashing by making some simple changes to where you put your try clauses.

In the server do this:

```
protected void sendMsg(String msg){
    for (ObjectOutputStream out2 : outList){
        try {//try moved to this line
            out2.writeObject(msg + "\n");
        }//end of try
        out2.reset();//reset even if an error occurs so that the next message sends smoothly
    catch(IOException ioe){} //catch moved to this line
    }//end of for each
}//end of sendMsg()
```

Instead of this:

```
protected void sendMsg(String msg){
    try {
        for (ObjectOutputStream out2 : outList){
            out2.writeObject(msg + "\n");
            out2.reset();
        }//end of for each
    }//end of try
    catch(IOException ioe){}
}//end of sendMsg()
```

Note how the try has been moved to surround the message sending only (not the for loop), so that if one message fails to send then it will just skip it and send the next message in the for loop instead of crashing.

Now do the same to your `protected void sendArrayList(){` method, move the try/catch to surround these two lines only instead of surrounding the for loop:

```
out2.writeObject(clientNames);
out2.reset();
```

The following change should also be made so that you don’t send messages to the recently disconnected client:

```
                if ( (((String) obj).length() > 4 ) && ( (String) obj).substring(0, 4).equals("////") ){

                    //first copy the users name so we can use it in our message:
                    String disconnectedUser = clientNames.get(index);
                    //now remove the disconnected user before you do anything else:
                    clientNames.remove(clientName);
                    //now you can send your message without causing the error because the disconnected client has been removed from the clientName list:
                    sendMsg(clientNames.get(index) + " has logged out of the chat room.\n");

                    sendArrayList();

                } //end of if
```

Comment: I also suggest you rethink how you check if a client is disconnected, because a client cannot always send the close message `out.writeObject("////" + clientName);`, especially if the client is force closed, or if the network connection is lost.

Comment: Thank you sir, it helped :). Instead of Default close operation I set up a window listener for window closing.